# Vivado/TCL get_cells with dynamic regexp

Tags: tcl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I've written a small example of what I want to do and what output I recieve.

```
set a 0
set tmp [get_cells -hier -regexp [ format .*latch\[%d\].* $a ] ]
puts [ llength $tmp ]

set tmp [get_cells -hier -regexp {.*latch\[0\].*}]
puts [ llength $tmp ]
```

Output:

```
WARNING: [Vivado 12-180] No cells matched '.*latch[0].*'. [C:/dev/jesd204b_clock_gen/logic/proj/xilinx/2017.4/Test1/Test1.srcs/sources_1/tdc/TDCConstraints.tcl:24]
0
16
```

As you can see, the first get_cells call returns a warning and 0 elements, even though it has the same regex expression as the second call, which succeeds
What did I do wrong, and how can I fix this behaviour?
Many thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not really the same however:

```
% format .*latch\[%d\].* $a
.*latch[0].*
% puts {.*latch\[0\].*}
.*latch\[0\].*
```

You will have to use braces in `format`, or double escape the string, i.e. use:

```
format {.*latch\[%d\].*} $a
```

Or

```
format .*latch\\\[%d\\\].* $a
```